# Issue with cv::Mat::zeros initialization

Tags: opencv

my problem is just astonishing. This is the code

```
 #define NCHANNEL 3
 #define NFRAME 100
 Mat RR = Mat::zeros(NCHANNEL, NFRAME-1, CV_64FC1);

double *p_0 = RR.ptr<double>(0);
double *p_1 = RR.ptr<double>(1);
double *p_2 = RR.ptr<double>(2); 
cout<< p_0[NFRAME-1] << endl << p_1[NFRAME-1] << endl << p_2[NFRAME-1] << endl;
```

And the output is: 0 0 -6.27744e+066 . 
Where is that awful number come from? 
 it seems I'm printing a pointer or something rough in memory. 
 (uh, 0 is the value of all other elements, of course).

Comment: its working fine for me. is it your original problematic part ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing after the last element of Mat. If you use `NFRAME-1` for initialization then the last element has `NFRAME-2` index.